# Fourier series of $f(x)=\Bigl\{\begin{smallmatrix}-10,&-2≤x≤-1\\x,&-1<x<1\\10,&1≤x≤2\end{smallmatrix}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

To find a Fourier series of this type( three cases ) I don't know how to work with it :

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-10,&-2≤x≤-1\\x,&-1<x<1\\10,&\,\,\,\,\,1≤x≤2\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x,&0≤x≤1\\1,&1<x≤2\\3-x,&2<x≤3\end{cases}$$

$f$ is $4$-periodic ?
And $g$ is $3$ - periodic

Any help or Hints?

Thanks

Comment: In order to get proper alignment with `\begin{cases}`, prepend a `&` on the conditionals.

Comment: Aren't there any examples in your textbook or your notes?

Comment: @BernardMassé I don't have , do you have a book with such examples?

Comment: @Tomas Houbaze. I found 2 in my home library, but the books are 50 years old... And for the next few weeks (or months) all libraries I have access to are closed. If you have access to a library, you can look up one of them: Kaplan, Advanced Calculus.